# How to find codewords from constraint equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, message-coding, code-generation

**I have edited this question to include more information about what algorithm I wish to use etc.**

Say if I have a linear binary code with parity check matrix

$$H = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

My understanding is that binary linear codes in this form can have a parity check matrix in standard form: $$H = [A | I_{n-k}]$$
Where $A$ is an $(n-k) \times k$ matrix, and $I_{n-k}$ is the $(n-k) \times (n-k)$ identity matrix.

Here,

- $n$=block length (i.e length of a codeword in the code)
- $k$=dimension (i.e length of original message vector)

My understanding is that we can use this parity check matrix $H$ to define a generator matrix: $$G=[I_{k}|-A^{T}]$$ this is made easier over our binary field as $A=-A$

I want to find the codewords using mathematica.

I think that there should be $q^{k} = 2^{4} = 16$ codewords. (this is because there should be $q^{k}$ codewords satisfying $Hx^{T}=0$ and $x \in C \forall Hx^{T}=0$)

It is also my understanding that $x=uG$, where $u$ is a message vector, $x$ is a codeword and $G$ is the generator matrix.

$k=4$, meaning that the length of any message vector $u$ must be $4$, so $u \in \mathbb{F}_{2} ^{4}$. I think this means that the vectors of $u$ are $0000, 1000,0100,0010,0001,1100,1010,1001,0110,0101,0011,1110,1011,1101,0111,1111$ (all the 4-tuples of 0s and 1s).

As such, we could potentially get the codewords from $x=uG$

However, I am really unsure as to how I would go about constructing the codewords with mathematica?

Comment: Can you explain how you would approach the problem in general, apart from the Mathematica part? In other words, what algorithm do you want to implement?

Comment: You should not assume that we know what you mean by the word `codewords` or how `q == 2^4 == 16` relates to your matrix `H` or what `H` represents. Provide some context for what you are trying to do. "I know how I could solve a general linear algebraic equation in this form." Then show that as part of the context.

Comment: Just to add the context https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming(7,4)

Comment: By the way, I am suggesting to close this question as it has nothing to do with Mathematica (least of the problem) and it shows no own work (more of a problem).

Comment: @yarchik apologies, I have added an answer (which I believe satisfies my question) with my own work to remedy this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check matrix is defined by:  h.c==0 , where h is the check matrix and c a code word.

We may write an equation with modulus 2 like:

```
vars = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7};
Reduce[{h . vars == 0}, v, Modulus -> 2]
```

[image: x1 == C[1] + C[3] + C[4] && x2 == C[1] + C[2] + C[4] && x3 == C[4] && x4 == C[1] + C[2] + C[3] && x5 == C[3] && x6 == C[2] && x7 == C[1]]

To get the code words, we need to replace the c's by 0 or 1. For this aim, we change the equations into rules and apply them to the variables xi. Then we create a table where we set the different c's to 0 or 1:

```
v = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7};
rul = Reduce[{h . v == 0}, v, Modulus -> 2] // ToRules
Flatten[Table[
   v /. rul /. 
    Thread[{C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4]} -> {i1, i2, i3, i4}], {i1, 0, 
    1}, {i2, 0, 1}, {i3, 0, 1}, {i4, 0, 1}], 3] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: 2 and 3 should not appear in the answer. I am sure this is a binary code. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming(7,4)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the modulus 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code also provides the codewords as per my question:

Construct a linear binary code with parity check matrix in standard form
$H=[A|I_{n-k}]$, where $H$ is an $(n-k) \times n$ matrix

```
H = {{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
   1}}
```

We can obtain $G$ from $H$, if $H$ is in standard form such that
$G=[I_{k}|-A^{T}]$

```
A = Take[#, 4] & /@ H

Atranspose = Transpose[A]

Ik = IdentityMatrix[4]

G = Join[Ik, Atranspose, 2]

G // MatrixForm
```

This outputs the matrix
$$G = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

The codewords $x$ can  be found using the equation $$x=uG$$ where $u$ are the message vectors (in our case all possible binary strings of length $4$)

```
u = Tuples[{0, 1}, 4]

codewords = MatrixForm[Mod[# . G, 2]] & /@ u
```